# Typescript code coverage of multiple __extends declarations

Tags: typescript, code-coverage, karma-runner, istanbul

When it compiles my code, TypeScript includes an __extends declaration at the top of every file:

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
```

This works fine behind-the-scenes, but it creates an inconsistency when it comes to using something like karma-coverage to generate reports.  This declaration contains two function calls and a branch in the code (the || usage), which only ever get exercised on the first declaration, leaving dozens (if not hundreds) of subsequent declarations for which there is no coverage.  This makes a file with otherwise 100% code coverage look sorely uncovered in the coverage reports.

Has anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 2.1, typescript support for external helper library, all the emitted function goes to the `tslib` package

```
npm install --save tslib
```

change your tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        //all the other stuff
        "importHelpers": true
    }
}
```

then TypeScript will automatically import `tslib` package if necessary
like example below

```
var tslib_1 = require("tslib");

var MyClass = (function (_super) {
    tslib_1.__extends(MyClass, _super);
    function MyClass() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    return MyClass;
}(controller_1.Controller));
```

Comment: This appears to be the current correct solution, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I found a work item at the typescript codeplex. I hope the typescript guys solve this issue soon. You can find more on that here: [typescript workitem 2002](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2002)

Comment: Thanks, we actually filed a similar ticket, noted as a duplicate.  In the meantime we forked the compiler and implemented the _noExtends options ourselves, and it works like a charm ;)

Comment: CodePlex issue is now closed. Try: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1350

Answer (score 3):

I just created a function in my scripts task that appends a header to the top of any file that uses inheritance. This boosted by code coverage a lot. I'm using istanbul, so my function looks like this:

```
function istanbulIgnoreTypeScriptExtend() {
    var tsExtends = /^var __extends =/;
    return through.obj(function(file, enc, done) {
        if (file.isBuffer() && tsExtends.test(file.contents)) {
            file.contents = Buffer.concat([
                new Buffer('/* istanbul ignore next: TypeScript extend */' + os.EOL),
                file.contents
            ]);
        }
        this.push(file);
        done();
    });
}
```

I could actually publish it as a gulp plugin, but I'm hoping there are new ways to fix the problem soon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using the function [@jedmao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129847/jedmao) provided in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26321994/227622) with a gulp task.
I've modified it slightly to handle the `var __extends=` not being the first thing in the file (e.g. if you have a `'use strict'` or a `/// <references` tag). You should probably also use `os.EOL` as jedmao did rather than a `\n` as I am doing here.

```
var gulp     = require('gulp');
var through2 = require('through2');

gulp.task('my-gulp-task', function() {
    gulp.src('*.ts')
        .pipe(myTypeScriptCompiler())
        .pipe(istanbulIgnoreTypeScriptExtend())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('myDestFolder'));
});

function istanbulIgnoreTypeScriptExtend() {
    var tsExtends = /var __extends =/;
    return through2.obj(function(file, enc, done) {
        if (file.isBuffer() && tsExtends.test(file.contents)) {
            var rows = file.contents.toString().split('\n');
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                if (rows[i].indexOf('var __extends =') === 0) {
                    rows.splice(i, 0, '/* istanbul ignore next: TypeScript extend */');
                    break;
                }
            }
            file.contents = new Buffer(rows.join('\n'));
        }
        this.push(file);
        done();
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The typescript compiler will generate this on top of every file that has the `extends` keyword. The only way to make this a single use is compile to a single js file with `--out` compiler flag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is just a restatement of the problem.  Obviously compiling to a single file would generate almost useless coverage reports.  Seems like TSC should have an option for this, or there should be a way to ignore these multiple instances via a karma-coverage option... or even a creative shell-scripting solution?  Curious what others may have done.